# How can I tell jenkins that the execution of script failed?

Tags: jenkins, stderr

How can I tell `jenkins` that the execution of a script failed (to get a red icon)? Should I write something in stderr? Or should I return a non-zero value in script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins follows the usual Unix convention to determine whether a command failed -- it examines the exit code. So you would need to return a non-zero value from whatever you're running.